# Getting HTML value of selectbox in PHP variable in the same file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

My HTML code creates select options

```
<select name ="sortBy" id="sortBy" onchange="getValue(this)">   
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="total">Total Medals</option>
    <option value="gold">Gold Medal</option>
    <option value="silver">Silver Medal</option>
    <option value="bronze">Bronze Medal</option>
</select>
```

My attempt at using Ajax to read the value from the select box

```
function getValue(obj){

   $("#sortBy").on( 'click', function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'main.php',
        data: { source1: obj.value },
        success: function( data ) {
            console.log( data );
        }
    });
});

}
```

My PHP code that creates a variable

```
$sortBy   = $_POST['source1'];
echo $sortBy;
```

However I get an error message saying source1 is an undefined index in the PHP code. I assume it isn't getting the variable from JS.

All of these are on the same document (main.php). I'd like the PHP variable to changed depending on the variable gotten in JS. How can I fix this? Thanks
How can I fix this?

Comment: Check value of `obj.value` in JS

Comment: obj.value gets the correct value from the select box.

Comment: you have added on("click"), add on("change") OR    $("#sortBy").change(function () {

Comment: Doesn't seem to fix the issue. My variable is still not being defined in PHP

Comment: What the result of `var_dump($_REQUEST)` in PHP?

Comment: are you using post method in form?

Comment: var_dump: `array(5) { ["country1"]=> string(3) "FRA" ["country2"]=> string(3) "GBR" ["country3"]=> string(0) "" ["country4"]=> string(3) "SWE" ["submit"]=> string(6) "Submit" } `

Comment: Yes, I am using post throughout the document

Comment: Ok, the form contain other input, and the dump you show me is like the form were submitted.

Comment: I am getting sql data from another php page through _GET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing between fonction `getValue` that use param `obj`, and the binding `.on` context that use `this`

Use `data: { source1: $( this ).val() },` instead.

And i think that `getValue` function is useless because ajax will be called on `click` event. (for `<select>`, you could prefer `change` event)

You have the choice, bind the event using attributes like `onchange`, or bind using jQuery. Choose one and remove the other.

See this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9votqpev/), that show you the request is correctly sent. (You have to open the console to show the ajax call). If you have something wrong in your code, it's in another place.

**EDIT**

The error is only due to the fact that PHP for the AJAX call and HTML+jQuery code are in the same page. So loading the page prompt you the POST error because you are not in the AJAX call.And loading the page in browser will always perform a GET request (when not in form submit context of course ^^).

To prevent it just add this test in the PHP code : (this code test for XMLHttpRequest)

```
if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
    if(isset($_POST['source1'])) {
        echo $_POST['source1'];
    } else {
        echo "Something went wrong, we are in AJAX call but no data given!!";
    }
}
```

Comment: Replacing the data: with the code you offered seems to still cause the error where my php variable isn't defined.

Comment: Did you try to set `type:'POST'` in uppercase?

Comment: Yes I just did, still no result

Comment: The url is my document name correct? If yes, still cannot get this to work.

Comment: Simplify your code, remove all; add just the `<select>` with the peace of jQuery and try it. If it works, add the rest of code one by one...

Comment: Done. My entire PHP document http://pastebin.com/YPRdvp4b I still get the error where my php variable is undefined

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138793/discussion-between-jodev-and-pete).

Answer (score 1):

Your code says: when the value of the option change, add an event listener on click to that option that do the job.
This should work better:

```
$.ready(function({

$("#sortBy").on( 'change', function () {
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'main.php',
    data: { source1: $("#sortBy").val() },
    success: function( data ) {
        console.log( data );
    }
});
});

});
```

Comment: Still faced with my PHP variable being undefined. I am writing AJAX inside a JQuery script just below my HTML. Might that be the issue?

Comment: In console: $("#sortBy").on( 'change', function () { : missing formal parameter

Comment: I run your code and now I n¿know what the problem is:
replace
    $("#sortBy").val()
with this:
    $(this).find('option:selected').val()